# How to create a .sock file for unix_stream

Tags: linux, unix-sockets

I am new to this socket programming in linux I want to send a log file i.e eve.json This file is provided by suricata and they have already defined some setting in their configuration yaml to send this file over unix socket . I add a sample below

```
eve-log:
  enabled: yes
  filetype: unix_stream #regular|syslog|unix_dgram|unix_stream|redis
  filename: eve.sock
```

How do we create such .sock files for client and server What is written in them , what configuration do we have

If please can anyone provide any article related to this .sock file creation for server and client.

Comment: Does this help? https://serverfault.com/questions/358866/create-unix-named-socket-from-the-command-line. You can also make a socket file in C I believe ([beej's guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/))